# Products visible only on the search page

Tags: magento2.3, catalog, catalogsearch

Products are visible only on the search page, but not available on the category page.

Admin products visibility on Catalog and Search:
[image]

***Category page screen:***
[image]
***Category page filters show the count of products:***
[image]
***Search success:***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the required product's visibility to `catalog, search` and reindex the indexes using the following command ;

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to write that, but everything is already done - indexer:reindex, cache:flush, indexer:reset and etc. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

The checklist for whether items are in stock follows :

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a
   stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through
   Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
8. You must refresh your Cache /Indices, just to make sure.

Comment: Done, but no result.

Comment: Applied the following code into the SQL:

CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));